# Plotting Nested Lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

How to plot a linked list such as:

```
ll = {{a, b}, {{c, d}, {{e, f}, {}}}}
```

The expected result is a tree with the nodes and edges ordered as follows.

[image]

The empty / null nodes should not be displayed. The starting node can have a root label or a user defined label.

Comment: Sounds like you could do most of this with `TreeForm` if you use the right option settings.

Comment: As Sjoerd Smit sayd, `TreeForm@list` is almost that what you want... and a bit more, the empty list is displayed correctly

Comment: Thanks @SjoerdSmit the answer uses exactly that ! I've accepted this as a correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended in the comments, use [`TreeForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeForm.html)

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

ll = {{a, b}, {{c, d}, {{e, f}, {}}}};

TreeForm["root" @@ (ll /. {} :> Nothing), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Text[
     If[#2 === List, "", 
      Framed[Style[#2, 18], Background -> White, 
       FrameStyle -> White]], #1] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! Brilliant.

Comment: Perhaps this tweak is useful: tf[ex_, root_: "root"] := 
  TreeForm[root @@ (ex /. {} :> Nothing), 
   VertexRenderingFunction -> (Text[
       If[#2 === List, "", Style[#2, 18]], #1] &)];